# Lost Contact List

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

I am trying to find my contact list in Gmail. I have looked in settings to try and find why it disappeared but could not find an answer. Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

your contacts are nowadays under: **https://contacts.google.com/**

**GIF:** **https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJcyr.gif** (open in new tab)

[image]